# Swagger - make docs secure

Tags: azure, swagger, swashbuckle

I am using Swagger with the nuget swashbuckle package.
It all seems to work ok.

How do I keep it secure? I don't want anyone to be able to access Swagger docs by  going to `path-to-mysite/swagger`.

Note: I am using Azure too, so wondering if I can use anything here - I tried turning on authentication, but I think that blocks anyone from calling the APIs.

I followed this method around *7mins:30* in t[his video](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/connect-2015-what-s-new-in-app-service-api-apps/).

I'd still like anyone to use the APIs, I just want the docs available to me though.

Comment: You want to have you API available anonymously, but not its documentation?

Comment: Yes, the documentation is useful to me. the API's are not written for others to code against, but only for them to use the API from within an App

Comment: Is there going to be any type of authentication on top of your API to distinguish who's gonna call it?